# Relationship between two entities in a database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables, one named as `employee` , contains the details of an employee, with the *primary* keys as `employee_id` and `employee_name`.
The other named as `assignment`, with *primary key* as `assign_id`.
Now, there are two columns in the table `employee`. One is `preference_1` and other is `preference_2`. These both can contain the `assign_id` from table `assignment`. Preference 1 has to be filled by all the employees and preference 2 is optional but no more than two preferences should be allowed.
How do I link both these tables ?

Comment: Make `preference_1` and `preference_2` foreign keys to `assignment`?

Comment: If you could add a sort of schema of what the tables look like, it would help.  Do a little looking into ISNULL and Joins.

Comment: @David type of relationship?

Comment: @code.atodi: Looks like many `employee`s to one `assignment` for the first and to potentially zero `assignment`s for the second.  A many-to-many would probably be preferable here if there would ever be a need for more than two, though *constraining* it to two would be more complicated in that scenario.  And so far the only requirement in that regard has been "no more than two."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

preference_1 and preference_2 should be two separate tables, not inside employee table.  You can have an employee_ID inside the pref_1, pref_2 AND assignment tables.

Comment: I made a similar mistake - a table for customer contacts, with 4 fields - "Contact 1", "Contact 2".. I'm sure querying it is possible but not without some unnecessary effort.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this

```
SELECT e.employee_name, a1.assigment_name AS firstPreference, a2.assignment_name AS secondPreference
FROM employee e
    JOIN assignment a1 ON e.preference_1 = a1.assign_id
    LEFT JOIN assignment a2 ON e.preference_2 = a2.assign_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Since, `preference_2` is optional; make `preference_1` (OR) `preference_1`/`preference_2` `foreign keys` to assignement's assignment_id. Means, `preference_1/preference_2 references assignment(assignment_id)`.

Talking about the relationship, to me it looks like a `many-many` relationship; cause a employee may work on multiple assignment and similarly a single assignment may be assigned to more than one employee.

Table creation:

Put `NULL` constraint for `preference_1` since it must be filled by employee; like `preference_1 int not null` but make preference_2 a `nullable column` like `preference_2 int null`.

That will make sure, every employee has at least one assignment. If optional pref_2 is filled then he/she will work on 2 assignment.

While querying, you can do a join like

```
select e.* from employee e join assignment a on 
e.preference_1 = a.assignment_id 
and isnull(e.preference_2,0) = a.assignment_id
```

Comment: i think by the question, an employee has to work on at least one and at most two assignments. how to restrict that?